# Detect significant trend changes

Tags: r, time-series, data-analysis

I would like to detect the dates where a trend curve significantly changes using R. The red dots are the points in time where I see a significant changed, these should be detected. Small fluctuations should be ignored.

[image: Trend curve]

I have tried the `breakpoints` functions which finds the dates indicated by the dotted lined. I don't see how these lines correlate with the data.

Example data from the chart:

```
structure(c(431.510725286867, 421.634186460535, 379.627938613016, 
425.906255600274, -14.1367284804303, -384.10599618701, -611.193815166686, 
-460.535003689942, -309.875390598749, -84.9820334889592, 217.330882967973, 
437.111949107673, 738.919896124628, 752.79552200685, 804.851028725362, 
757.869760812822, 1197.91301915761, 1567.88256933466, 1794.97067632374, 
1644.31215300884, 1493.6528224525, 1268.75973855711, 968.432034953716, 
743.503624686386, 510.63191994943), .Tsp = c(2016.66666666667, 
2018.66666666667, 12), class = "ts")
```

Comment: Look at [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/139660/detecting-changes-in-time-series-r-example), despite I've tried a couple of their hints but without any nice results. Maybe you can post a question on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). It seems you do not have a friendly TS.

Answer (score 1):

Compare the forward and backward finite difference, and filter out small values.

Explicitly: compute ∆(*t*) = *x*(*t*+1)-*x*(*t*) and ∇(*t*) = *x*(*t*)-*x*(*t-1*), then d(*t*) = ∆(*t*)-∇(*t*)=*x*(*t*+1)-*x*(*t*-1), and keep the *t* for which |*d*(*t*)| > ε, where ε captures what you call a small fluctuation.

In your case, *d* = c(NA, -32.1, 88.3, **-486.3**, 70.1, 142.9, **377.7**, 0.0, 74.2, 77.4, -82.5, 82.0, **-287.9**, 38.2, -99.0, **487.0**, -70.1, -142.9, **-377.7**, -0.0, -74.2, -75.4, 75.4, -7.9, NA). Which is greater, in absolute value, than ε=200 for t=c(4, 7, 13, 16, 19), exactly your 4 red dots.

Of course, the threshold of ε=200 may be chosen with more rigor (on a histogram of *d* the value of 200 jump in the face).

You may also want to smooth down the fluctuations by taking an average on a few points rather that the previous and next value : *d<sub>n</sub>*(*t*) = *x*(*t*+*n*)+ ...+*x*(*t*+*1*)-*x*(*t*-1)-...-*x*(*t*-n).

Comment: both 'delta formulas' appear to be the same. Is there a typo?

Comment: Yes, there was. Corrected.